# Probability of finding polynomials in a field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $K$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and $n\ge q,n\in \mathbb N$.Determine the probability when choosing a polynomial from the set of polynomials of degree $n$ from $K[X]$ , it will have no roots in $K$. Can somebody help me, please? I'm not so good at polynomial.

I've found that the polynomial $X^q-X$ has all elements of $K$ as roots.

Comment: Have you tried for small $n$, like $1$ or $2$? What did you get then? What about $n = 3$?

Comment: It's easy to count the polynomials of degree $n$.  I would try to count the ones with at least one root.  Such a polynomial can be written at a product $k$ linear factors times a polynomial of degree $n-k$ and no roots.  Therefore we get a recurrence relation.  I'd make some examples and see what happens.  I don't know if this works, but it's how I would approach the problem.

Comment: Numerical calculations along the lines I suggested strongly suggest that the answer is $\left(1-\frac1q\right)^q,$ but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the subspace $V$ of polynomials in $K[x]$ of degree $<q$. Let's turn $V$ into a set of functions $F(K,K)$ from $K$ to itself by evaluating the polynomials at all the points of $K$. This is a $K$-linear mapping $ev:V\to F(K,K)$.

- The polynomials $\in V\setminus\{0\}$ can have at most $q-1$ zeros in $K$, so the kernel of $ev$ must be trivial. Hence $ev$ is injective.
- Because $\dim_KV=q=\dim_KF(K,K)$, it follows that $ev$ is a bijection. In other words, we get each and every function in $F(K,K)$ exactly once by evaluating the polynomials in $V$.
- The conclusion of the previous bullet then holds for each coset of $V$ in $K[x]$ as well (we can extend the definition of $ev$ to all of $K[x]$).
- Given that $n\ge q$, the collection of polynomials of degree exactly $n$ is a union of disjoint cosets $f+V$ where $f$ ranges over some set of representatives.
- The probability of a function in $F(K,K)$ not having any zeros is $(1-1/q)^q$. By the previous bullets this holds for all the cosets $f+V$ as well, and therefore also for any union of such cosets.

Comment: This is lovely.

Comment: Please have a look at the [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137672/an-unusual-polynomial-identity) I have posted.